# Fetch request returns nothing

Tags: javascript, forms, fetch

I am trying to perform a `Fetch` request to an external API, and it should return some JSON data. I have tested the request in my browsers console and it worked fine, however as soon as I add this code to run when I submit a form, it doesn't seem to do anything. No error, it just does nothing.

This is my function:

```js
async function getStats() {
    let username = document.forms["usernameSearch"]["username"].value.toLowerCase();
    let response = await fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=${key}&name=${username}`);
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
}
```

This is the HTML for the form:

```html
<form name="usernameSearch" onsubmit="getStats()">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

No matter what I type in, when I click submit on the form the page just refreshes and the console shows nothing.

Comment: `key` variable isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behavior of onsubmit.
You can change the attribute value to

```
<form name="usernameSearch" onsubmit="onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); getStats()"">
```